# Rails: Sending PUT Request using curl/Postman to update an attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl, strong-parameters, postman

I was reading Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial book and in the Strong Parameters part it says

> a malicious user could send a PATCH request as follows:
>
> patch **/users/17?admin=1**
>
> This request would make user 17 an admin, which would be a potentially serious security breach.

Then I decided to be a "malicious user" myself so that I could better understand it.

So I added :admin to the list of permitted attributes in the user controller and used curl in Linux to send a PUT/PATCH request and see in the console if the admin attribute really gets updated by sending the malicious request.

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:3000/users/17?admin=1
```

Firstly it complained **"Can't verify CSRF token authenticity"**, then I commented out

```
# protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```

in the application controller and also eliminated some before_actions simply trying to get it work but I got stuck at the point where it complained

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: user):
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:49:in `user_params'
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:37:in `update'
```

I then realized that I might have to pass the user param as a hash of hashes of params to get it work. How do I achieve this in curl or Postman (a chrome REST client)?

Answer (score 5):

To simulate a nested attribute in the URL query, you can write something like : 
`http://localhost:3000/users/17?user[admin]=1`
But It is more accurate to do it in the body of the request if it is a PUT one.

In postman, you can simply switch to the TEXT mode and write your JSON

```
{"user": {
    "admin": 1
    }
}
```

But if you do that, don't forget to add the required Headers for the Rails server to understand you are PUTing JSON :

```
Accept:application/json
Content-Type:application/json
```

Good luck !

Comment: Thanks sir, you really made it work!! But I have one more question. After I sent the PATCH/PUT request using Postman, it seems that the request was sent for multiple times. In the development log, except the first commit taking about 169ms, there are also about 10+ blocks of information appearing as follows, could you please explain the reason?

Comment: Started PUT "/users/17" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-23 10:25:09 +0800  
Processing by UsersController#update as JSON  
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"admin"=>1}, "id"=>"17"}  
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 17]]  
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction  
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('j@w.l') AND "users"."id" != 17) LIMIT 1  
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction  
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/17  
Completed 302 Found in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)

Answer (score 1):

It's late to response to the post's owner, but I just wish it might help others.

`curl -v -XPUT -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://localhost:3000/users/17 -d '{"user": { "admin": "1" }}'`

I'm not sure whether the value 1 need to be quoted or not. You can try it with or without the quote.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -v -XPATCH http://localhost:3000/users/17 -d '{"user": { "admin": 1 } }'
```

Has it's a `PATCH` (or `PUT`) header, you can't add `?admin=1` to your request.